# How to handle connection loss page in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, guard

What I want is that, If the network is not available, and the user tries to navigate to the next page `ConnectionLost` Component would be there.

But if there is no network and user do not take any action means not navigating to the second page. then there should not be a connection-lost page. The user should stay on the current page.

For that, I have implemented canActivate guard as the following code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private network: NetworkService) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (window.navigator.onLine) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (!this.isConnectionLostComponent()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/connection-lost'], {skipLocationChange: true});
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  private isConnectionLostComponent() {
    // check whether connection lost component is added on not
    return this.network.isActive;
  }
}
```

It's working fine except for one condition. 
That is if I click back or forward from the browser, its update URL `connection-lost` to the **address bar**

How could I solve this problem?
Can see the sample [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8dhxw)

**steps to produce the issue:**

1. Click banner(Button) -> URL change to '/banner'
2. Click brand(Button) -> URL change to '/brand'
3. Disconnect network on that brand page
4. Click back from browser-> ConnectionLostComponent and url is '/brand', that's okay
5. Click back again -> ConnectionLostComponent but url is also changed to '/connection-lost'. that's what I'm facing the problem.

I just don't want to update the URL with '/connection-lost', for that I added `skipLocationChange: true` option to `router.navigate` method in the `NetworkGuard`, But still it's not working.

Comment: You could store the last visited URL, and if the users goes back to it, then prevent your condition ? You can't do much else, as the browsers forbid you to know if the user clicked on the back button.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: @trichetriche I can check last visited URL but how could I prevent user to go back until he/she is online, and I have added a similar type of condition in isConnectionLostComponent() method, please check my updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little bit of search, and with help of @AlokeT's answer. I got a solution to this problem.

@AlokeT's suggestion is showing connection loss page as soon as the user lost his/her network. but my requirement is to show that connection loss page while he/she tries to navigate to another page.

And In this answer, I just added, that missing part.

For that, I just update that `isNetworkStopped` flag from Guard, and because every CanActivate guard executes before navigation starts. So connection lost component would show while the user changing the path.

There is a code of `NetworkService` which I'm using in NetworkGuard,

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NetworkService {

  online: boolean;
  isNetworkStopped = false;

  constructor() {
    this.online = window.navigator.onLine;

    fromEvent(window, 'online').subscribe(e => {
      this.online = true;
    });

    fromEvent(window, 'offline').subscribe(e => {
      this.online = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Here in above code I just added a flag **`isNetworkStopped`**. And updated that flag from `NetworkGuard`, means while the user tries to navigate to next page and found no network.

And also removed navigation from NetworkGuard.
See my below, updated code of `NetoworkGuard`

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NetworkGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private network: NetworkService) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (this.network.online) {
      return true;
    }
    this.network.isNetworkStopped = true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

And based on that flag I managed to show ConnectionLost component.
For that `ConnectionLost`component is added on condition based to root component's template.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="!networkService.isNetworkStopped"></router-outlet>
<app-connection *ngIf="networkService.isNetworkStopped"></app-connection>
```

And from ConnectionLost component, if the user clicks on the reload button. By checking network connection I updated **`isNetworkStopped`** flag of `NetworkService`.

Comment: Since the networkService already has a "online" property, why it still need the isNetworkStopped flag?

Comment: Yes, @peanut it's true, but as user navigating to another component then I'm changing this(isNetworkStopped) flag. so that user can see connection lost component while he/she changing the route, not as soon as connection lost.
That's my primary requirement.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know is it the right solution or not for you but what I did in my project is following.

> app.component.ts

```
constructor(){
this.onlineOffline = Observable.merge(of(navigator.onLine),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(map(() => true)),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(map(() => false))
    );
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="onlineOffline | async; then thenTemplate; else elseTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-template #thenTemplate>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  <app-no-network></app-no-network>
</ng-template>
```

Let me know if it is working the way you need to implement it or not.

Comment: this is a good answer and I tried it before, but this time I want to show 'app-no-network' component on navigation. not as fast as the user disconnected from the network.

Comment: BTW what the benefit of doing that? I just want to know. @RaviSevta

Comment: A user can see current page content if there is no network. taking action is a secondary thing. @ AlokeT

Comment: So you can make a transparent overlay and activate it when there is no network so user only can see content, but unable to do anything. also add `<app-no-network>` a property called `show` which will show a small changes to the page like **YouTube** does on its android app.

Comment: but I have to show a connection break UI on no internet.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188720/discussion-between-aloket-and-ravi-sevta).